# What areas of Hadoop's network usage are interesting to observe and profile, as part of a college project?

Tags: hadoop

I'm planning to profile a part of Hadoop's MapReduce for a grad school project, focussing on the network related aspects. I have found a few papers regarding the same, but I was wondering if there are some well known areas of study, and some existing resources abut the same.

I don't need to break any new ground. Even if I can reproduce any well known existing pattern of network utilization, it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to come up with the entire list of network related bottlenecks that could occur in an MapReduce scenario would be to understand how each and every daemon works with each other.

Get to know the entire flow of a MapReduce job. You can find this at a blog post I had written sometime back - [Introducing Hadoop](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/introducing-hadoop-part-ii/)

The JobTracker and the TaskTracker are the daemons that actually do the work in an Hadoop enviroment. So looking into how the JobTracker assigns tasks and how the TaskTracker responds is an area that is prone to bottlenecks in case of network issue.

The MapReduce "Shuffle and Sort" phase is another keyword you could look up wherein network issues can cause major latency.

Also, as you must be already knowing that each node in the cluster needs to have password less ssh access to the other nodes. This is another area that could be affected due to network issues.

I don't have any specific links to point but I hope I was able to point you in the correct direction.